# Creating a DataFrame in a For Loop Produces Nan Error

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, jupyter-notebook

While exploring the Olympics dataset on Jupyter Notebook, I was trying to find out which sport is the oldest from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results).

[image: Here's a screenshot to the first 5 rows of the data]

This is the code I currently have:

```py
sports = olympics.set_index('Sport')
sport_name = olympics['Sport'].unique()

for sport in sport_name:
    years_played = sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].max() - sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].min()
    print(sport, years_played)
```

The code returns me this result:

```
Basketball Year    80.0
dtype: float64
Judo Year    52.0
dtype: float64
Boxing Year    112.0
dtype: float64
```

[Here's a screenshot to the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3b1N.png).

Note there is a string "Year" in front of each float number.

Then I tried turning this into a DataFrame with this code:

```py
sports = olympics.set_index('Sport')
sport_name = olympics['Sport'].unique()

for sport in sport_name:
    years_played = sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].max() - sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].min()
    rows = []
    rows = rows.append([sport, years_played])
    pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ['Sport', 'Years Played'])
```

Which returned an error: `KeyError: nan`. [Here's a screenshot to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6k8C.png).

**I have two questions:**

1. Why does the loop return a string "Year" before every float result? I tried using the same line of code outside the loop (using `.loc`, then subtracting `.max()` with `.min()`) and there was no string before the result, just the resulting float number.
2. What's causing the `nan` error?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh, I can see why that was hard to debug. What's missing from your output screenshot is the last part

```
Year    80
dtype: int64
Year    52
dtype: int64
...
Year    12
dtype: int64
Year    0
dtype: int64
0
```

Notice how the last line doesn't follow the pattern of the rest! If you inspect `sport` and `years_played` at the end of the loop, nothing appears to be amiss. But if you inspect

- `sports.loc[sport[0], ['Year']]` and
- `sports.loc[sport[-1], ['Year']]`

and compare them you'll find out what's happening.

The first is a DataFrame. You'll see it is indexed by an index called `Sport`, every entry of which is `Basketball`. Like this:

```
            Year
Sport           
Basketball  1992
Basketball  2008
Basketball  1952
Basketball  2000
Basketball  1972
...          ...
Basketball  2004
Basketball  1996
Basketball  2004
Basketball  2008
Basketball  2016

[4536 rows x 1 columns]
```

However, the second is a Series:

```
Year    1936
Name: Aeronautics, dtype: object
```

... which is what you get if you select *only* one row from a DataFrame.

I suspect you kind of know this already - I notice that you wrapped `'Year'` in a list, which ensures you get a DataFrame back in the first case. Only one column is called `Year`, so if you don't do this you'll get back a Series:

```
sports.loc[sport, 'Year'] ->

Sport
Basketball    1992
Basketball    2008
Basketball    1952
Basketball    2000
Basketball    1972
              ... 
Basketball    2004
Basketball    1996
Basketball    2004
Basketball    2008
Basketball    2016
Name: Year, Length: 4536, dtype: int64
```

(spot the difference with the previous output)

Now, if you do `sports.loc["Aeronautics", "Year"]` you just get back an integer, `1936`, because you've selected a single cell. This then would lead to an error, because an `int` doesn't have a `max` and `min` method, which your code is expecting.

One solution is to force it to always come back with a DataFrame. You can do that like this ...

```py
for sport in sport_name:
    data = sports.loc[[sport], ['Year']]
    years_played = data.max() - data.min()
    print(sport, years_played)
```

... but that just makes the real reason for your problem apparent, rather than solving it. Now `data.max() - data.min()` comes back with

```
Year    0
dtype: int64
```

This is a pandas series with one entry. The index of the Series is `"Year"` (because that was the column name of the DataFrame `data` created above). That's why you were getting the strange output. The actual fix is simple - simply select the single value, now that we've ensured we'll *always* get a series:

```py
for sport in sport_name:
    data = sports.loc[[sport], ['Year']]
    years_played = data.max() - data.min()
    print(sport, years_played[0])
```

---

The second bit of code you posted will never work:

```py
for sport in sport_name:
    years_played = sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].max() - sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].min()
    rows = []
    rows = rows.append([sport, years_played])
    pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ['Sport', 'Years Played'])
```

The last line creates a new DataFrame from the single row you've put into the list but doesn't assign it to anything. However, in my case it also doesn't throw an error, so I suspect my version of `pandas` (`v1.1.0`) has different behaviour to yours. Regardless, the issue will be the same I'm sure: that `years_played` is either a `Series` or an `int` depending on whether there were multiple years in which the sport was played or not.

Answer (score 2):

Hi kim and welcome to StackOverflow. I'll try to explain better than I can.

### Question 1

The loop return the result in this format:

```
dtype: int64
Basque Pelota Year    0

dtype: int64
Aeronautics 0
```

As you can see `Basque Pelota Year    0` contains `Year` but `Aeronautics 0` don't have it.

In the first case the type of `years_played` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` but in the second case is `<class 'numpy.int64'>`. That means that in the first case you have to access the value of the series like: `years_played['Year']` but in the second case if you try this it will raise the exception `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` because it is an `int64` type and not a series.

In your case would be enough to check the type of `years_played` and get the value based on the type:

```
print(sport, years_played['Year'] if isinstance(years_played, Series) else years_played)
```

Take a look the the reference for the [built-in function `isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). You can also use the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) anyway avoid the usage of `type()` because it simply returns the type of an object whereas, `isinstance()` returns `true` if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

### Final code

Essentially the final code will result in something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.series import Series

olympics = pd.read_csv("athlete_events.csv")

sports = olympics.set_index('Sport')
sport_name = olympics['Sport'].unique()

for sport in sport_name:
    years_played = sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].max() - sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].min()
    print(type(years_played)) 
    print(sport, years_played['Year'] if isinstance(years_played, Series) else years_played)
```

Another way to solve the problem could be to solve the type problem at the start:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.series import Series

olympics = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\carlo.zanocco\Desktop\archive\athlete_events.csv")

sports = olympics.set_index('Sport')
sport_name = olympics['Sport'].unique()

for sport in sport_name:
    years_played = sports.loc[sport, 'Year'].max() - sports.loc[sport, 'Year'].min()
    print(type(years_played)) 
    print(sport, years_played)
```

Here I have changed `sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].max() - sports.loc[sport, ['Year']].min()` with `sports.loc[sport, 'Year'].max() - sports.loc[sport, 'Year'].min()` so it will return only the value as type `<class 'numpy.int64'>` and you don't need to check the type when printing the result.

### Question 2

The error `KeyError: nan` means that you are trying to access a Key that doesn't exist. In you case the key `nan`.

Essentially this exception map the not found key.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the prompt reply, @Carlo Zanocco. What's causing the difference in class type between Aeronautics and Basque Pelota?

Comment: The problem is explained in the second solution, use `sports.loc[sport, 'Year'].max() - sports.loc[sport, 'Year'].min()` to align the type to be `<class 'numpy.int64'>`. The problem is that you create a Series with `['Year']`

Comment: @kim if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.